# Scroll to element and position it in the middle of view

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to autoscroll to the middle row in the order book.

I have orderBook div, in which table with orderBook is placed. And one of the rows of that table has an id middleRow. What I'm trying to do is to scroll and position that row in the middle of the orderBook.

Expected result is shown on the picture:

[image]

I've tryied jQuery scrollTo function, but it puts middle row on top of the screen, as shown below:

> $('#orderBook').find('.tableBody').scrollTo('#orderBookMiddleRow')

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/

You can specify an offset for your scroll like this:

```
$('#orderBook').find('.tableBody').scrollTo('#orderBookMiddleRow', 500, {offset: -$(window).height() /2})
```

Here's a really simple proof of concept: http://jsfiddle.net/6k8asog1/

**Edit:**  Here's OP's revised code for scrolling to the center of #orderBook, rather than the window:

```
$('#orderBook').find('.tableBody').scrollTo('#orderBookMiddleRow', 500, {offset: $('#orderBook').offset().top - $('#orderBook').height() - $('#orderBookMiddleRow').height() })
```

Comment: doesn't work as expected... I think because offset is set on window height and orderbook is not on the top of the window

Comment: $('#orderBook').find('.tableBody').scrollTo('#orderBookMiddleRow', 500, {offset: $('#orderBook').offset().top - $('#orderBook').height() -  $('#orderBookMiddleRow').height() })

Comment: above one works as expected, just played around with your code
pls correct and I'll mark as solved